# grunt task undefined not found

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm fairly new to Grunt and trying to run a custom task using `grunt-protractor-coverage` plugin but I get the error

> Warning: Task "undefined" not found. Use --force to continue.

My script is as follows.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.registerTask('test', 'Log some stuff.', function() {
    console.log('Logging some stuff...');
  });

  grunt.initConfig({
        instrument: {
              files: 'server/**/*.js',
              options: {
                lazy: true,
                basePath: "instrumented"
             }
        }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-protractor-coverage');

  grunt.registerTask('instrument');

  // Default task(s)
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['instrument']);
};
```

Comment: Who runs the Grunt? is it npm-script? Could you show the definition of the script which execution forces Grunt's run and leads to this error?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before, and solved it by updating grunt. Would be a good first step to try:

`npm --global update grunt-cli`

Comment: thanks but that didn't solve the problem. I'm surprised how does the task 'test' work while instrument doesn't